# How to implement Bit Flags in VBScript

Tags: vbscript

Ok, two disclaimers,

1. I do not work in Vbscript but need to use it a little for an HMI project
2. I am looking at doing this because this application limits total "tags" or variables

So basically what I am trying to achieve is the following;
a unit8, foo, has the value 5 which is b00000101 now I would like to view this as 8 binary values a pseudocode way of doing this would be

```
IF foo AND b00000001 <> 0 THEN 'sudo read
.....

foo = foo OR b00000010 'sudo write 1

foo = foo AND b11111101 'sudo write 0
...ect
```

I think it will be something like

```
&foo AND &b00000001 <> 0
```

is this practical in VBScript again I am well aware this is not standard practice but in between tag limitations and HMI input limitations it might actually make the most sense in this application.

Comment: Would suggest reading about [Using Bitwise Operators in VB](https://www.jameshbyrd.com/using-bitwise-operators-in-vb/).

Comment: Failing that, a [quick google search for `vbscript bit flags`](https://www.google.com/search?q=vbscript+bit+flags) brings up a few resources to look at.

Answer (score 0):

You could give something like this a try which uses Bitwise Operators to read and write the bitwise flags.

```vb
Function GetFlag(value, bit_num)
    Dim bit_mask
    If bit_num < 32 Then bit_mask = 2 ^ (bit_num - 1) Else bit_mask = "&H80000000"
    GetFlag = CBool(value AND bit_mask)
End Function

Function SetFlag(value, bit_num, new_value)
    Dim bit_mask
    If bit_num < 32 Then bit_mask = 2 ^ (bit_num - 1) Else bit_mask = "&H80000000"
    If new_value Then
        SetFlag = value OR bit_mask
    Else
        bit_mask = NOT bit_mask
        SetFlag = value AND bit_mask
    End If
End Function

'Define constants to store the flags (maximum of 32)
Const FLAG_SUDOREAD = 1
Const FLAG_SUDOWRITEONE = 2
Const FLAG_SUDOWRITETWO = 3

'Set the flags
Dim options
options = SetFlag(options, FLAG_SUDOREAD, True)
options = SetFlag(options, FLAG_SUDOWRITEONE, False)
options = SetFlag(options, FLAG_SUDOWRITETWO, True)

'Read the flags
WScript.Echo "FLAG_SUDOREAD = " & GetFlag(options, FLAG_SUDOREAD)
WScript.Echo "FLAG_SUDOWRITEONE = " & GetFlag(options, FLAG_SUDOWRITEONE)
```

Output:

```
FLAG_SUDOREAD = True
FLAG_SUDOWRITEONE = False
```

---

#### Useful Links

- [Using Bitwise Operators In VB](https://www.jameshbyrd.com/using-bitwise-operators-in-vb/) *(Excellent resource for learning Bitwise operators and how to use them)*